# How to save the json keypoints detections from mtcnn to a text file

Tags: json, opencv, save, jupyter, keypoint

I am trying to use Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch and the first step is to get your image trough MTCNN in order to get the landmarks for the face. I use the general demo code from MTCNN.
It works great and i get what i expected but i also need to save the json file results to a txt file.

```
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('figure.jpg')
cv2.imshow('',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
detector = MTCNN()
faces = detector.detect_faces(image)
for face in faces:
    print(face)
    {'box': [142, 109, 237, 289], 'confidence': 0.9997594952583313, 'keypoints': {'left_eye': (212, 221), 'right_eye': (323, 223), 'nose': (265, 280), 'mouth_left': (209, 322), 'mouth_right': (319, 327)}}
    def create_bbox(image):
    faces = detector.detect_faces(image)
    bounding_box = faces[0]['box']
    keypoints = faces[0]['keypoints']
    cv2.rectangle(image,
                (bounding_box[0], bounding_box[1]),
                (bounding_box[0]+bounding_box[2], bounding_box[1] + bounding_box[3]),
                (0,155,255),
                2)              
    cv2.circle(image,(keypoints['left_eye']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
    cv2.circle(image,(keypoints['right_eye']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
    cv2.circle(image,(keypoints['nose']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
    cv2.circle(image,(keypoints['mouth_left']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
    cv2.circle(image,(keypoints['mouth_right']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
    return image
    marked_image = create_bbox(image)
    cv2.imshow('',marked_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and i get this json file

**"{'box': [142, 109, 237, 289], 'confidence': 0.9997594952583313, 'keypoints': {'left_eye': (212, 221), 'right_eye': (323, 223), 'nose': (265, 280), 'mouth_left': (209, 322), 'mouth_right': (319, 327)}}"
**

It works perfectly, but i need to **save these values to a txt file**.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the array of json into a single json object and write it into a file. Below shows how you can achieve that.

```
import json

json_result = {}
with open("result.txt","w") as result_file:
    for n,face in enumerate(faces): 
        json_result[str(n)] = face
        
    json_string = json.dumps(json_result,indent=4)
    result_file.write(json_string)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply .  I get "NameError: name 'faces' is not defined"

Comment: faces is the result from the function detector.detect_faces(image)